# How to Add Android contacts list

Tags: android

I am trying to add contact list. When I click add button then show test message but Internal it does not add contract. I have given permission READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS. But Why it does not add contract list I can not understand.

```
private void addContact(String name, String number) {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { name }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contracts Exist",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            ContentProviderOperation op1 = ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                            "com.google")
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                            "bappy@gmail.com").build();
            ops.add(op1);
            ContentProviderOperation op2 = ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            name).build();
            ops.add(op2);
            ContentProviderOperation op3 = ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            name).build();
            ops.add(op3);

            try {
                cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contract saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     String DisplayName = "XYZ";
 String MobileNumber = "123456";
 String HomeNumber = "1111";
 String WorkNumber = "2222";
 String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
 String company = "bad";
 String jobTitle = "abcd";

 ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
 ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
     .build());

 //------------------------------------------------------ Names
 if (DisplayName != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
     ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
     DisplayName).build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
 if (MobileNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
     newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
 if (HomeNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
 if (WorkNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Email
 if (emailID != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
 if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
 try {
     getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

modify it according to your need

Comment: this link may help http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html